# Having trouble connecting to a local server in Python

Tags: python

I'm currently following this tutorial on how to make a multiplayer game using python: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=McoDjOCb2Zo

I'm currently trying to connect to a server file with a network file. Running the server file prints out the correct piece of information but once I try connecting to it with the network file nothing happens.

Here is my server code. When it runs it prints out "Waiting for a connection, Server started
(I have removed my IP address, but I know that I have the right one in for when I run my code)

```
import socket
from _thread import *

server = "***.***.*.**"
port = 5555

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:
    s.bind((server, port))

except socket.error as e:
    str(e)

s.listen(2)
print("Waitng for a connection, Server Started")

def threaded_client(conn):
    conn.send(str.encode("Connected"))
    reply = ""
    
    while True:
        try:
            data = conn.recieve(2048)
            reply = data.decode("utf-8")

            if not data:
                print("Disconnected")
                break
            else:
                print("Received", reply)
                print("Sending: ", reply)
            
            conn.sendall(str.encode(reply))
        except:
            break
    print("Lost Connection")
    conn.close()


while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print("Conneced to: ", addr)

    start_new_thread(threaded_client, (conn,))
```

And here is the code for my network

```
import socket

class Network:
    def __init__(self):
        self.client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.server = "***.***.*.**"
        self.port = 5555
        self.addr = (self.server, self.port)
        self.id = self.connect()
        print(self.id)

    def connect(self):
        try:
            self.client.connect(self.addr)
            return self.client.recv(2048).decode()
        except:
            pass

n = Network()
```

When I run this code after initializing the server, it is supposed to print out "Connected"

Comment: Have you already confirmed that the client computer can ping the server computer?

Comment: Both files are being run on the same computer so I imagine that it should be able to ping itself if that's the correct terminology?

Comment: If you are running it locally, use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`

Comment: I swapped out my IP address for the 127.0.0.1, however the network file still didn't print that it had connected

Comment: It's possible something else on your computer is already using that port... try a different one? I've verified the code works fine on my computer, so the code itself isn't the problem. P.S. The script you're calling the "network" is what is more commonly called a client: a server runs, and one or more clients connect to it.